# How to load a python/unicode tag as a unicode string in python with ruamel

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel in the following way:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
print yaml.load('!!python/unicode aa')
```

Wanted output:

```
u'aa'
```

Actual output:

```
<ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar at 0x106557150>
```

I know of a hack that could be used with the SafeLoader to give me this behavior:

```
SafeLoader.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:python/unicode', lambda _, node: node.value)
```

This returns the value of the node, which is what I want. However, this hack doesn't seem to work with the RoundTripLoader.

Comment: Are you sure these three lines produce that output? The scalar `aa` has no tag, and I cannot reproduce this with Python 2.7 and `ruamel.yaml` version 0.15.35

Comment: Even with the added `!!python/unicode` this will not give that output. You still seem to have  some other program that what you show here. Please provide the version of Python and ruamel.yaml, are you running Linux, macOS or Windows?

Comment: Nope, I just copy pasted the code once again into `ipython` and run precisely those 3 lines with the same exact output (except for the object id, of course). I'm running on Mac, with Python 2.7.10, `ruamel.yaml==0.15.35`.

Answer (score 0):

the first 'u' means the string was encoder by 'utf-8', so if you pass 'u'aa'' into the function, it just feed the string which is 'aa'. So you can pass s"u'aa'" to get output u'aa'.

Comment: There was a mistake in my example. I revised it to use the `!!python/unicode` tag, which is the crux of the problem.

Comment: the output seems like a instance of the class. You can use python -m pdb to check the input data to load function.

Comment: The output _is_ indeed the instance of the class, and it's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I just want the value in this object (in the example's case `u'aa'`).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something funny with `ipython`'s handling of printing classes. In that it doesn't take into account the `__str__` method on the class `TaggedScalar`.

The `RoundTripConstructor` (used when doing a round-trip-load) is based on the `SafeConstructor` and for that the `python/unicode` tag is not defined (it is defined for the non-safe `Constructor`). Therefore you fall back to the `construct_undefined` method of the `RoundConstructor` which creates this `TaggedScalar` and yields it as part of the normal two-step creation process.

This `TaggedScalar` has a `__str__` method which, in a normal CPython returns the actual string value (stored in the `value` attribute). IPython doesn't seem to call that method.
If you change the name of the `__str__` method you get the same erroneous result in CPython as you are getting in IPython.

You might be able to trick IPython assuming it does use the `__repr__` method when `print`-ing:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import TaggedScalar

def my_representer(x):
    try:
        if isinstance(x.value, unicode):
            return "u'{}'".format(x.value)
    except:
        pass
    return x.value

TaggedScalar.__repr__ = my_representer

yaml = YAML()

print yaml.load('!!python/unicode aa')
```

which gives

```
u'aa'
```

on my Linux based CPython when the `__str__` method is deactivated (i.e. `__str__` should be used by `print` in favor of `__repr__`, but IPython doesn't seem to do that).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed answer. But it's not just IPython. It's bigger than that. For example, my initial problem was when trying to dump to JSON. I'd try that, and get an exception saying that TaggedSalar was not JSON serializable.

Comment: @mcouthon And that was in a normal (i.e. CPython) on your Mac?

Comment: Yep. Same environment. Just replace the `print` call in my example with `json.dumps` and you'll get the exception I'm talking about.